# How to define a Class which is accessible in all classes in C#?

Tags: c#, module

Am new to C#, but have a plenty of experience of VB.net, now my issue is that there are no modules in C# and  i need to define a class which is accessible in all classes and i don't know how to do it.
For example I have a "classProject" and I need to make it accessible everywhere, so in vb.net , I will define it in module like below.

```
Module ModuleMain
Public tProject As New ClassProject
End Module
```

Now, I need to do same in C#.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `public class YourClassName { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your case:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public static class classProject
    {
      int myIntvar = 0;
      string myStringvar = "test";
    }
}
```

And you can use this `static` class in your other classes like:

```
public class Test
{
  int intTest = classProject.myIntvar;  //will be 0
  string stringTest = classProject.myStringvar; // will be test
}
```

You can use the variables in the static class since a static variable shares the value of it among all instances of the class. When you create multiple instances of `classProject` class, the variables `myIntvar` and `myStringvar` are shared across all of other classes in your project. Thus, at any given point of time, there will be only one integer and one string value contained in the respective variable's.

Comment: Thank you @Rahul, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a `static` class. You can reference the access modifiers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extends your other classes to class father (ClassProject) And you can access to it with youur children classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
//[access modifier] - [class] - [identifier]
public class Customer
{
// Fields, properties, methods and events go here...
}
```

[see more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes)

Comment: Let me explain you in more detail, i have forms through which i will get data, now i want to save these data in some class eg. ClassProject, now i have some other class eg ClassMaterial, where i want to use data stored in ClassProject. Now where i will define my classProject.

Comment: as Chobo said below you should create a public static class

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain me through some code @Ozlachy.

Comment: @AnasAhmed, if you're not familiar with access modifiers for C#, there are plenty of tutorials available to assist you.

I recommend taking a look with a quick Google search and there are plenty of options available.

The Microsoft documentation has plenty of code examples for you too:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members